# Use variable as expression in ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

This code works:

```
<div ng-include src="'Test.html'"></div>
```

This code doesn't:

```
<div ng-include src="ctrl.URL"></div>
```

(`ctrl.URL` is set to `"Test.html"`).  I also set it to `'Test.html'` and `"'Test.html'"` with the same results.

How can I successfully convert this into an expression for use in `ng-include` src? I think I am missing some knowledge on how strings get parsed but I was pretty sure `'Test.html'` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I am too incompetent to rename my own variables. ctrl.URL was really ctrl.URl. Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/mfha6/) will help you.

HTML and templates:

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include src="template.url" onload='myFunction()'></div>
  </div>

<!-- template1.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
  Content of template1.html
</script>

<!-- template2.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    <p ng-class="color">Content of template2.html</p>
</script>
```

The controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.templates = [{
        name: 'template1.html',
        url: 'template1.html'},
    {
        name: 'template2.html',
        url: 'template2.html'}];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: This works until I want to change the string variable. I define a string called URL in my code to 'Test1.html', and then I assign this variable to the $scope.templates variable. It doesn't work after I assign it.